Can you please advise on kerning?
Despite as much as I practice and as much as I squint and turn things upside down I've never been confident with my kerning, perhaps a little imposter syndrome, perhaps I'm just terrible at it.
So...how does the below feel to you? Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated.


I think the "RTAI" is always going to look a bit odd - primarily due to the "RT" and "AI" combined with the fact it's a "cluster" of sorts. Overall it looks fine to me.. I might go the other way and increase kerning everywhere except the "RTAI" so it doesn't stand out as much. But that's more personal preference than anything.

A bit crammed, but if that's what you're after, it looks ok just like that.

Not enough for a full answer, but there's not enough gap between the words on the same line. Especially Certain in, that gap feels just about as substantial as the gap between AIN because they kinda line up. At a glance I either read it as CERTAININ and UNCERTAIN or CERTAIN IN UNCERTA IN.

I think the main issue is with the letters RTAIN. To be fair, I think this is always going to be a bit of a problem with such tight kerning, which is simply exacerbating the problem. However if you need really tight kerning, then I don't think there are that many options open to you.
This is a bit subjective, but what I would do is reduce the kerning of the TA pair, keep the RT pair the same, and increase the kerning of all the other pairs to compensate. I think this gives the letters a bit more room to breathe, more balance, and the problem seems to be less noticeable.


This looks way better to my eyes

It's not only how you adjust the spaces between the letters. This is like a placard which should be taken as a whole. In addition round C and O need special treatment because they look a little puny if they are placed like those more rectangular letters.
The next is a 100% subjective example how I would approach this and it cannot be proved right nor wrong. One can like or dislike it and he is as right as I am. I unfortunately do not have your font, but used another which also has round O and C among rectangular other glyphs.

The thin vertical line hopefully shows the special placing of the C.

It's a different typeface... not even close to the same aspects.

Absolutely true, but the difficulties with C and O are the same.

I would disagree since the C in your font has far more air around the caps.. and the R compensates for the T more. I don't feel the C and O were any issue in the question image - but maybe that's just me.

@Scott Absolute layman here but I did see the "C" issue after this answer pointed it out. Interesting. This design also separates the words more, mitigating some of the "crammed" feeling a commenter had and improving readability -- but that condensed appearance, including the word spacing, was probably purposeful design which is now partly lost.

As a rule of thumb, kern the problematic pairs first (like NC or RT, in your case), and adjust the rest to match the color, rather than start with pairs like IN, which can be as tight (and therefore as dark) as you want, but which other pairs won't be able to match. A display text containing a word like DOCTOR, for example, would have to be kerned loosely throughout to look even.

It's very tight (intentional i assume, for a poster or similar). Even so, the /T/A kern should be a little tighter (less space).
/E/S is slightly problematic (very slightly overtight); either add a very small amount of space, or edit the /E glyph to shorten the top arm (and therefore the middle arm a bit too).
